# Are using-declarations static?

Tags: c++, using-directives

I'm a bit confused about using-declarations. I understand that `using foo::bar;` imports the symbol `bar` from namespace `foo` into the current namespace, but does this happen statically or dynamically?

More specifically, do using-declarations lead to an overhead? Would it be possible to import different symbols with the same name depending on a condition? (that would be bad practice, but I'm curious all the same)

It feels like it should be static, but I can't find anything to confirm this...

Comment: The "symbol importation" is only conceptual; in practice, a `using` declaration on a namespace `foo` only tells the compiler that non-namespace-qualified symbols might refer to symbols that come from `foo`. There cannot be a runtime overhead, as symbols (mostly) don't exist at runtime. Whether there is a compile-time overhead is compiler dependent.

Comment: Thanks. That is actually much more helpful than the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Namespace resolution happens at compile time. You can not change them dynamically at run time.

One way to import different symbols depending on condition is to use preprocessor directives and macros:

```
#ifdef USEA
using a::f;
#else
using b::f;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`using` in `c++` is **compile-time** directive, i.e. it only affects how compiler resolves names during compilation

> Would it be possible to import different symbols with the same name depending on a condition?

Depends what condition you are talking about. In case preprocessor's condition like `#ifdef` yes it is possible. If you think about a run-time condition then no, `using` is not performed at run time

Answer (score 0):

Using declaration looks like any other declarations. It has its own scope depending on where it is written. You may not dynamically declare a variable.

Comment: I don't think OP was talking about `static` as in "file scope". I think it was more about static versus dynamic (ie: compile-time versus run-time)

Comment: @KABoissonneault Why have you decided that I am saying about the static storage duration?

Comment: I just don't think the notion of scope is relevant to this answer. As a proof, it had me confused about what your answer was implying.

Comment: @KABoissonneault It is the scope that prevents to declare two different entities (with rare exceptions as for example functions) with the same name. Othrewise you could write ("dynamically") for example if ( condition ) int x; else double x; However these two variables have their own scopes and are not alive outside the if-else statement.